# Video not playing after WPF MediaElement object in xaml is assigned a different MediaElement object

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I suspect this is a trivial issue that stems from my WPF noobishness, but have been trying to solve this for hours both by myself and looking at example code / searching stackoverflow with no luck, so here it goes. Many thanks in advance for reading.

I have a MediaElement object defined in the xaml:
`<MediaElement x:Name="Media" Background="Black" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" />`

In the xaml.cs, if I just use the Media object as is (as per code below) it works correctly, the video plays as it should.

```
Media.Source = new Uri("C:\\Video.mp4");
Media.Play();
```

but if I try to create a separate MediaElement object, load the video into it, and then assign that object to the MediaElement object defined in the xaml (goal is to preload video into the ME object for buffering purposes) the video doesn't play (see corresponding code below). Actually the sound plays but there is no video. I assume I need to do something to tell the object to refresh itself by invoking some event or something like that but can't figure out what/how.

```
MediaElement tmpme = new MediaElement();
tmpme.Source = new Uri("C:\\Video.mp4");
Media = tmpme;
Media.Play();
```

btw it's not an issue with timing/loading of video not having completed. I've tried to add a wait timer after the tmpme.Source= line to give video ample time to load but that makes no difference.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Create a new MediaElement object
MediaElement mediaElement = new    MediaElement();

// Load the video in the background
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("myvideo.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
mediaElement.LoadedBehavior =       MediaState.Manual;


// Assign the MediaElement object to another control in the GUI
myMediaElement.Source = mediaElement.Source;
myMediaElement.Position = mediaElement.Position;
myMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
myMediaElement.Play();
```

Comment: huh. it worked! (i did have to change "mediaElement.Play()" to "myMediaElement.Play()" (at very end) to get it to play. I guess reassigning myMediaElement is not ok, but swapping the source within is acceptable! thank you very much.

Comment: although on second thought isn't "myMediaElement.Source = mediaElement.Source" just causing the video to be reloaded again, this time within myMediaElement? Source is after all just a URI, it's the assignment of a value to Source that triggers the loading of the video. If that's what's happening then it wouldn't solve my issue.

Comment: Can you measure how long it takes to assign the source to the new object. If takes exactly the same time as mediaElement then it won’t be the right answer. One way to work around this, try populating the mediaElement right after you assign the source to a container in your GUI. Example, show a progressbar them hide and show your mediaElemnt after the video has been loaded. You may need to do that in the background (backgroundWorker or async).